# Does 20.04 support multi-touch gestures out of the box?

Tags: multi-touch

I don't have a touch display so am asking this question to see if it's worth purchasing one and also would like to know if there is any specialized setup required to get a multi-touch gesture display to work. Hoping this is a quick question for someone that already has gone though this evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried Ubuntu on a Lenovo-Yoga with touch screen.

Multi touch works (as described [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch)) but only on certain widgets. Entry fields for example were not supported (except 1 touch selection) and some more features just worked barely.
I really hate to say it, but the windows touch integration was far more elaborate - and I'm not a fan of that OS.

So it depends what you wanna do and what expectations you have.
Easiest way to test it would be with a live Ubuntu-USB on a laptop with a touch-screen if you can get your hands on one.

Last but not least I've tried several linux distros with Ubuntu as winner.

Answer (score 1):

On my device works gestures, if the three fingers to bring together, in this case open recent apps, and four fingers to the side to switch between windows... Yes, it works and everything seems to look quite decent, but multitouch does not work in games, such emulators as PPSSPP and Retroarch. In Retroarch, switching the video_driver to X11 mode completely disables the program, and switching the input_driver to "x" and "sdl2" mode does not lead to anything. I've been trying to get it to work with at least two indexes at the same time for a week now. But it doesn't understand neither the resolution nor the indexes of the simultaneous click... and it is sad.

Because I only have three things left that keep me going back to Windows all the time... it is correct to use the file manager, use the chrome browser (correctly select the text and copy it) and play games.

Comment: @user1194973 i'm curious what device you are using.